# Some String in more class java

Tags: java, android, string

i have a problem, i have to recall the value of a string from the main class to a secondary class, how can i access to the string on the main class from the second?
I got a first Class(LoginActivity) and a second class(DashboardActivity) I have to take the returning value of the LoginActivity (string username) in the dashboard, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When launching DashboardActivity, pass the String value as an Intent.EXTRA.

When launching:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DashboardActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("MyString", username);
```

And to get the value:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = bundle.getString("MyString");
```

Comment: since the answer may not be clear, when you create an intent to start the next activity you call `intent.putExtra(key, value);`

Comment: @toadzky I've added sample code. Thanks for the comment though!